# WebScraping from aspx page using WebClient C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-scraping, webclient, viewstate

I'm trying to crawl data from a aspx page, which have three dropdowns: State, District, and City.They are implemented as the dependency dropdowns with the server side post back.
I Have all the ids of the State, District, and the City.I am writing a Console application using WebClient to Post all three drop-down ids as a form data to the page. But every time it is redirecting to an error page. Can anyone help me to set all the drop-down values at a time with single post call?

Code Snippet:

```
var formValues = new NameValueCollection();
formValues["__VIEWSTATE"] = Extract("__VIEWSTATE", responseString);
formValues["__EVENTVALIDATION"] = Extract("__EVENTVALIDATION", responseString);
formValues["ddlSelectLanguage"] = "en-US";
formValues["ddlState"] = "19";
formValues["DDLDistrict"] = "237";
formValues["DDLVillage"] = "bcab59fd-35d2-e111-882d-001517f1d35c";
client.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36");
var responseData = client.UploadValues(firstPage, formValues);
responseString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseData);
```

Comment: What is the URL of that website?

Comment: Install fiddler http://www.telerik.com/fiddler and compare what the browser sends over the wire and what your c# webclient sends over the wire. Fix any changes.

Comment: http://210.212.41.167/frmSelectDistrict.aspx